# sencha cmd, how to generate a view in a subfolder?

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs5

When using the sencha cmd command: sencha generate view main, it will generate the view, model and controller. But not in the subfolder (I made a subfolder in the view folder).
Is it possible to generate the view in the current folder?

Regards, Chris.

Comment: You can just define the name with the name of the folder in the string like App.view.MyFolder.newView.js and then put this in your Application.js folder.  You can then reference the file however you want.  
For the main view you have to go alter the auto create in app.js or you'll get errors.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! sencha generate view foldername.test  worked! It created the test.js, testController.js and testModel in the direcotry [foldername]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, have you tried this:

```
sencha generate view main.Main
```

***main.*** would generate a subfolder for you.

Try it see if it works.